# Find the first and last span of a line

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph of text, where each word is wrapped in a span, and I would like to find the first and last span on each line, it will need to use the resize function and change depending on the screen size. I am looking to add a class / add padding. I am using the jQuery library already on the site so not against using that.

```
<div>
    <h2>
        <a href="#">
            <span>20</span><span>of</span><span>the</span><span>most</span><span>romantic</span><span>places</span><span>to</span><span>propose</span><span>in</span><span>Gloucestershire</span>
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

My jQuery so far looks like this

```
$( "h2 a span" ).each(function() {
    console.log( $( this ).position() );
});
```

My CSS is just basic CSS which can be seen here

```
div {
    width: 550px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
    h2 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 0px;
        width: 200px;
        display: inline;
        color: #fff;
    }
        h2 a span {
            background: #ff00ff;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }
```

I have this jsfiddle set up so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nshk5cvd/10/

The fiddle shows my left positioning for each span, i just need help finding hte first and last span on each line.

Comment: You can use $("h2 a span").first() and $("h2 a span").last()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the collection of spans, and:
If it's the first span in the collection, it's the first in a line;
If it's last in the collection, it's the last in a line;
Otherwise observe the offset from top and once it changes you know it's in a new line, so span at the current index is the first in a line, its previous sibling is the last of preceding line.

```
var spans = $( "h2 a span" ), refTop = 0, top = 0;
spans.each(function( i) {
    var $t = $( this ), top = this.getClientRects()[0].top;
    if( i==0 ){
        $t.addClass('first');
        // set the reference top position to match the first span
        refTop = this.getClientRects()[0].top;
    }
    if( i == spans.length - 1 ){
      $t.addClass('last');   
    }

    // if the top is greater than the reference it's the beginning of a new line
    if( top > refTop ){
       // if the current element is first, its previous sibling is the last.
       $t.addClass('first').prev().addClass('last');   
        // update the reference for next line pass
        refTop = top;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nshk5cvd/19/

Comment: Hi Thank you. this works pretty good. not hundred percent.

I have added a resize function, but came across a couple of problems

http://jsfiddle.net/nshk5cvd/17/

when there is only on word a line, I will need to do something different to the first and last span. 

when you go quite small and then back to large (in width) the first class never reappears.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nshk5cvd/19/ - get rid of `else` statements and execute the code on every element, and remove proeviously added first/last class names so it updates on resize.

Comment: I know i said it works a treat. Ive just moved the script over to my site (im using it within a slider) and ive come across another problem. if you take a look at the fiddle, you will see what i mean

http://jsfiddle.net/VYfCh/169/

Ive duplicated the h2, But not the script is adding the content from all the h2's into each other.

Comment: Also when you resize, theres a few places were the script doesnt kick in properly and there isnt the right padding being applied (padding applied through the .first and .last class)

Comment: @JordanSayner In both cases (wrapping words in spans and marking spans as first/last) you need to iterate over the collection of headers, not over a collection of all spans: http://jsfiddle.net/VYfCh/171/

Comment: That makes sense. Cheers, One more thing (will be the last I promise). 

The slider i am using is BX Slider ([link](http://bxslider.com/)), in which all slides have a caption. I am trying to fire the function when the slider transitions using the "onSlideAfter" callback built into the plugin. but it just caused me slider to crash.
would it work with this callback?
http://bxslider.com/examples/callback-api

Comment: the reason i need to fire it on slide transition is that currently firstlast function only works on the first slide (the one it loads on.),

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "h2 a" ).each(function() {
    $(this).children("span:first");//this is first span of this line
    $(this).children("span:last");//this is last span of this line
});
```

Comment: that just finds the first and last of each paragraph, not each line. if you look at the jsfiddle, the paragraph goes over to lines.

Comment: what i said line, i mean an `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of way of doing this. The $.each function gives you a counter in the parenthesis:

http://jsfiddle.net/nshk5cvd/13/

```
//Solution 1
$( "h2 a span" ).each(function(i) {
    if (i == 0 || i == $("h2 a span").length - 1)
    {
        console.log( $( this ).position() );
    }
});

//Solution 2
console.log($( "h2 a span" ).first().position());
console.log($( "h2 a span" ).last().position());
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the help.

But this doesnt quite work for what i want.

It has picked up "20" and "Glouestershire", but im also looking to pick up the words "to" and "propose"

so the first and last word of each line and not each paragraph/Header

Answer (score 0):

```
var first_span = $( "h2 a span:first" );
var last_span = $( "h2 a span:last" );
```

Caching the elements is always a good idea for performance.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bu82170f/1/

Comment: thanks for takign a look, But this doesnt quite work for what i want. It has picked up "20" and "Glouestershire", but im also looking to pick up the words "to" and "propose" so the first and last word of each line and not each paragraph/Header

Comment: It's first and last in a collection, not in a line.